# different buttons but same ajax call on blockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockui

I have a blockUI in which i ajax call another page through a series of buttons with same class but different attribute value(of tag). however, when i run the code, only value of first button gets submitted no matter what button i clicked. How can i modify this to send data associated with different buttons separately? Please help

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
var form_data = {
message: $("#message").val(),
data: $(".pageDemo1").attr("tab"),
is_ajax: 1
};
```

Comment: i am using class in case of buttons.They can be same

Comment: But your `.click()` handler is bound to whatever `#submit` is, not to the buttons with the common class. If you had `$(".pageDemo1").click(...)` then within the function you could use `$(this)` to get the particular button that was clicked. (I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to do, so I'm not posting this as an answer.)

Comment: I understand your point. I have a separate form(with id form1) outside, and the buttons are made using for loop somewhere else. If this is the case, how should i do it?

Comment: please reply.. It's urgent!

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$(".pageDemo1").attr("tab")` references all of the buttons, and when you are setting data to this, it is using the value of the first button it finds.

I'm not sure of the structure of your page, but using a more specific selector (or set of selectors) to the button you want would be the best way to ensure you are getting the right value.

If the button in question is the element being clicked on in this case, you could use `$(this).attr("tab")`. If it isn't, you'll have to walk the DOM from whatever element `$('#submit')` is.

Comment: I understand your point. I have a separate form(with id form1) outside, and the buttons are made using for loop somewhere else. If this is the case, how should i do it?